# Jquery Tools (tabs) + TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, jquery-tools

I'm trying to integrate [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) in [Jquery Tools Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html), but I  can't seem to do it.
When all is set, I simply get no error, nor a warning. I only get a blank textarea.

I tryed with other Tabs (Jquery UI), and with that solution I am able to see TinyMCE, but I would like to use Jquery Tools, because of it's simplicity in css and filesize.

Update: here's 2 examples: one using Jquery Tools and another Jquery UI

Example 1: [Jquery Tools](http://emanuel.wayacross.pt/TinyMCE_jQueryTools_Test/index.php)
Example 2: [Jquery UI](http://emanuel.wayacross.pt/TinyMCE_jQueryUI_Test/index.php)

Tinymce init:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true
    });
```

Thank you.

Bruno

Comment: please post your tinymce init, unfortunatly if there are errors in the init function they do not get displayed

Comment: I found a post with (i think) the same problem (at least, it was integrating tinyMCE with another component from Jquery Tools) and did not have any answer so far, so I really doubt if they're compatible..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638632/use-tinymce-in-an-overlay-jquery-tools-overlay

Comment: in FF 3.6 it looks like it gets initialized, but i cannot see any buttons

Answer (score 3):

I've got it!.

Jquery Tools hides all div's inside the tab's panels **by default**, and TinyMCE uses DIV's to show the buttons, so those DIV's were being hidden.

What to do?

In Jquery Tools Tabs CSS, tell it to only hide the first DIV by adding >.
Example:

instead of:

```
.panes div { display:none; }
```

put

```
.panes > div { display:none; }
```

This way, it will only hide the first DIV.

Thank you anyway Thariama

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be with one of the plugins. I suggest you remove all plugins (`plugins: "",`) and see what happens then. If it works as expected try adding plugin by plugin till you get the one that hinders tinymce to initialize. Button configuration is not crucial here. If the suitable plugin does not exist - the button simply does not show up, but inititialization won't stop because of this.

Comment: I tested it and disabling all plugins still produce the same result.

Comment: Check my answer Thariama. Thank's anyway :)